# How can I get an if conditional do only run once in onclick() function?

Tags: javascript, loops, if-statement, onclick

I'm writing in to see if I can hopefully get some help here.

I'm using pure javascript and I have a link that looks like this:

```
<li><a class="cube_size = cube_size<cms:show cube_size_code />" href="javascript:void(0)" 
    onclick="update_price('
    <cms:show cube_size_code />-
    <cms:show cube_size_weight />-
    <cms:show cube_size_price />-
    <cms:show cube_size />-
    <cms:show cube_size_price_2/>')">
    <cms:show cube_size /></a></li>
```

As you can see it has a onclick event called **update_price()** there's four **li's** with the same code but of course with different data pulled into the string from the CMS which btw is **CouchCMS**.

What I'm trying to do is get the code in the if statement to run only once, what's happening is every time I click the different links the function starts back over which means the do while will start back over:

```
var counter = 0;
function update_price(exp){
    var cube_options = exp.split('-');
    var cube_size_code = cube_options[0];
    var cube_size_weight = cube_options[1];

    do{
    counter++;
    if(cube_size_code == "FFRK"){
      cube_size_code = "GHIEQ";  
      }while(counter < 1);
     }
    }
```

I would greatly appreciate if you can provide a simple technique on how I can prevent the do-while from resetting on every click or besides a loop is there a way for the if block to execute only once? PLEASE HELP!

Comment: It's not resetting; JS only quits the loop after having run it for the first time, since the condition is checked at the *end* of the loop, which is usually exactly what you're looking for when you choose `do-while` as your loop type. Remove the loop and use `if(counter === 0 && cube_size_code == "FFRK") cube_size_code = "GHIEQ";` instead.

Comment: Sorry, it's supposed to be `counter++`